# How do I send value to a date picker in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to automate form filling using robot framework. Could pass values to text fields, drop down list etc, stuck at date. Anyone who has done please help.

Comment: Can you please provide us with some more information on the date picker, ideally the html/ javascript code so we can understand the type of data picker it is. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can send, e.g. a date 6 days from today, directly by setting the value of the datepicker element with javascript:

```
${my_date_to_select}= Get Current Date    UTC    6 days   %d/%m/%Y
Execute JavaScript  document.getElementById('ID_OF_YOUR_DATEPICKER').value='${my_date_to_select}'
```

NB: In order to use the keyword 'Get Current Date', you need to add the library DateTime in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Focus        jquery=[name=expDate]
Press Key    jquery=[name=expDate]    09255639
```