# Robot Framework - need date from JQUERY Widget date picker

Tags: robotframework

This query relates to using Robot Framework to select dates from a JQUERY Widget date picker.  The JQUERY code was developed elsewhere and I’m not in a position to post.

The approach tried was

```
MAXIMIZE BROWSER WINDOW

WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS  Arrival Date

click element      xpath=.//*[@id='ArrivalDateLabel']

click element      xpath=.//*[@id='dp1503657643051']/div/div/a[2]/span
```

**Error reported**

```
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=.//*[@id='dp1503657643051']/div/div/a[2]/span' did not match any elements.
```

**Analysis**

Screen shot  1 shows  that part of the date picker calendar is not visible during the running of the Robot Framework test and  I believe this may be the reason for this.  The solution referenced below does not seem to switch the label marked arrival in the screenshot.

[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP5FQ.png)

**Similar previous  query**

[How do I send value to a date picker in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415347/how-do-i-send-value-to-a-date-picker-in-robot-framework)

Comment: while I don't think this is the full fix the following seems to work for dates on one month e.g. Sept.    click element   xpath=.//*[@id='ArrivalDateDiv']/div/div[1]
        press key   link=10     \\13
        press key   link=11     \\13

Answer (score 0):

This is a "best efforts" fix.

*Open the calendar by clicking the label xpath. 
Using the key commands*

press key link=10 \13 - will pick the 10th 
press key link=11 \13  - will pick the 11th

The issue is my date selections are confined to one month.
I had to proceed on this basis but believe there must be a better solution.